# How to save/edit in ckeditor?

Tags: php, ckeditor

I am facing an issue with CKEditor and I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong here!!!

I am saving some HTML page which created using CKEditor in my PHP application and it getting saved properly. But when i want to edit the content,i am getting the content from DB and loading it into CKEditor. at this time all the class/id value which i gave previously is getting disappeared.

I am loding the value to CKEditor in using the below one.

```
<textarea name="pageContent" class="form-control" id="editor">'.$rowData->content.'</textarea>
```

[image: Value which i saved in the DB]

[image: When i load the content in CKEditor]

Comment: After some more debug in the js and CKeditor configuration i got the fix. Just need to add config.allowedContent=true; in the config files. for more information visit http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.config

Answer (score 0):

After some more debug in the js and CKeditor configuration i got the fix. Just need to add config.allowedContent=true; in the config files. for more information visit http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.config

Comment: Actually, your solution is not the most recommended one. Instead of disabling Advanced Content Filter (ACF) you should [adjust it to your needs](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/guide/dev_acf-section-automatic-mode-and-allow-additional-tags%2Fproperties) and allow the additional content that you want to allow.